# Importing 2 dimensional array from integer text file in Python without Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am absolutely new to python coding and need help on the question below :
I have a text file that contains the following information

No of use-cases: 2

Deadlines: 1 2 3 1 4
Bonus: 20 40 10 10 20

Deadlines: 4 1 2 2
Bonus: 20 30 10 40

I want to read this into array of 2Dimensional array like below

[[1, 20], [2, 40], [3, 10], [1, 10], [4, 20]], [[4, 20], [1, 30],, [2, 10], [2, 40]] and so on.. depending upon the number of pairs available i.e. essentially double the count of number of use cases.

Can someone help me achieve this in python without numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my solution:

```
strt = 'Deadlines: 1 2 3 1 4 Bonus: 20 40 10 10 20'
tmp = [el for el in strt.split(' ') if el.isnumeric()]
out = []
spl = round(len(tmp)/2)
for i, el in enumerate(tmp[:spl]):
    out.append([tmp[i], tmp[spl:][i]])
out
>>>[['1', '20'], ['2', '40'], ['3', '10'], ['1', '10'], ['4', '20']]
```